# Error: Netprobe failed to start. Logfile for netprobe could not be created

Tags: linux, terminal, server-side, itrs

I am setting up the netprobe on the company servers. I was successful in installing and starting netprobe on other servers but only one server showing the following error. The only difference was someone already tried installing it before me but created softlink with the name of active_uat1 and he didn't created the the netprobe.

I created the ITRS netprobe successfully. But it failed to start and show the Error:
Netprobe failed to start. Logfile for netprobe could not be created

I checked in the netprobe folder also. There is no log file there.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to permission issue, can you try changing the permission of the file netprobe.linux_64 to 755 under the main directory of softlink active_uat1.

Secondly delete previously created netprobe under netprobe/netprobes

Thanks,